# sas9.4 (windows10) only can read the 1st folder in path, but fail in reaching other folders in path

Tags: windows, path, sas

it seems my SAS cannot access all folders in the path, i am running sas9.4 on windows10.

in sas9.4, when i run below code:

```
data _null_;
format x $10000.;
x=sysget('path');
put x=;
run;
```

it returns full path of various folders:
x=C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib; C:\xampp\mysql\bin;C:\xampp\mysql\lib; ......(and other folders' path)

then, in sas, when i run 
libname mysqllib mysql user=xxxxx .....

return errors:

> ERROR: The SAS/ACCESS Interface to MYSQL cannot be loaded. The
>   libmysql code appendage could not be loaded.

Actually, I already have libmysql.dll under my ...\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\ (i.e. the 3rd folder in the path)

anyway, i try putting the libmysql.dll under the first folder in path (i.e. `C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4;`) and run again this "libname mysqllib mysql user=xxx" ..... , it works successfully!

Then i deleted this dll under above \9.4 and now try putting this libmysql.dll in the 2nd folder in path (i.e. C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;), and run this "libname mysqllib mysql user=xxx", it fails again.

So, i doubt SAS cannot successfully load in other folders in the path, except only able to load the 1st folder, am i right?

any suggestion? thanks very much.

Comment: I can tell you now it's not anything to do with "reading just the first folder in the path".  You shouldn't ever need to move anything under the SASFoundation\9.4 folder.  Did you happen to make any changes to `sasv9.cfg` by any chance (or is your shortcut to SAS pointing at an older version of sasv9.cfg)?  That is the file that sets the paths used by the various SAS modules.  This sounds like it's more a question for SAS support and less something suitable to stack overflow.

Comment: Per [this note](http://support.sas.com/kb/19/250.html), I would doublecheck that you don't have a too old (or too new) version of MySQL in a different location in the path.  It's possible that version is being picked up in the cases where you're not putting it in the root directory.